# In Outlook 2016 for Mac, how do I delete ALL events of the primary calendar?

Tags: mac, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

If you Google for a solution to this, you would get:

- Change to list view
- Select all (Cmd-A)
- Delete

The problem with this approach is that it only deletes the current time view. And you can only select month as the biggest time period. So, if I, say, accidentally import my ics calendar file twice, and this calendar happens to stretch from 2002 until jan 2017, I would be in serious trouble as I would then have to go through every month from 2002 - 2017 in order to delete all events.

Also, there seems to be no way to delete the primary calender nor to create a new one in order to set it to the primary thus allowing the first one to be removed.

Also tried to remove the event files from the data path where Outlook stores its stuff but to no avail.

Surely, there must be a way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was struggling with this as well and found following solution:

1. Select your primary calendar and then go to "View" -> click on "List"
2. Now you can only see all items of one month
3. So go to the search field and then make an advanced search
4. Select "Start Date" -> "Any Date". Voila, there you have all dates
5. You should check if in this list it is really all the dates you want to
   delete and if yes go <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> -> "delete"